# Dynamic Image Footer Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to turn my footer into ad banner that changes images every 30 seconds. I am using set interval to call the function that pulls these images. However when I switch pages the interval still is in operation. I want that on each new page it stops the interval gets an image place it into the footer then changes it every 30 seconds. Should I set the footer to be a certain type because sometimes the image doesn't load and when it finally does it overlaps some content.

my code is below:

```
  //footer ads function
 function adsFunction() {
  var adurl = "http://kewsplus.com/includes/ads.php";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: adurl,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache : false,
        jsonp : "onJSONPLoad",
        jsonpCallback: "footeradscallback",
        crossDomain: "true",
        success: function (data) {
         //alert("success");
        },
        error: function(){ 
            //$.mobile.changePage("./error.html");
            alert("error with footer");
        }
});
}

//callback for footer ads
function footeradscallback(rtndata) 
{ 
for(j=0;j<=rtndata.length -1;j++)
{
    var data = "<img src="+rtndata[j].ad_url+" alt="+rtndata[j].ad_name+">";
}
$('#ads').html(data);
}

//when loading a page
$(document).on( "pagebeforeshow", "#somepage", function( e ) {
clearInterval(timerId);
adsFunction();
timerId = setInterval(adsFunction, 30000);
});
```

Comment: This will reduce ad clicks according to this [report of Jakob Nielsen](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/auto-forwarding/)

Comment: @jantimon then what do you suggest

Comment: `$.mobile.activePage.find('#ads').html(data);` try this, should work even without clearing interval, in case you have `#ads` in all pages.

Comment: Don't use an interval at all.

Comment: @Omar how can the function be replicated every 30seconds then without an interval